# Product price Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I start using Prestashop 1.7 and i have problems to display the price with taxes on product page. I have tried many things, but all of them faild.
Anyone knows a solution for this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is going to config each gruop of clients, and in the configuration page you have the option to see the price with or without taxes.

Go to: Shop Parameters -> Customer Settings, then go to Gruops tab and edit all of them changing this option:

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I'm glad. I would be very thankful if you mark my answer as "Accepted". Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to find this settings.